# is_trial_period stays "on" in Apple's Receipt Sandbox

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, receipt-validation

I'm encountering an issue while debugging Apple's in-app purchase receipt. It seems the field "is_trial_period" stays *true* although the purchase has already expired. 
To my understanding Apple defines short periods for debugging subscriptions, as seen here:

[Testing In-App Purchase Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)

Do those times apply for trail periods as well?

Comment: In the sandbox environment is_trial_period won't work. This will only work in production and by the way in sandbox apple will never issue a trial period.

Comment: @Jad as it seems the is_trial_period works and appear in a separate receipt as seen in the answer below.

Comment: @Jad I think that used to be true but now Sandbox is issuing trial's correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Apple issues a separate transaction for the trial period.

Here is an example excerpt of a receipt from Apple:

```
"latest_receipt_info": [
    {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "onemonth_freetrial",
        "transaction_id": "1000000328795138",
        "original_transaction_id": "1000000328795138",
        "purchase_date": "2017-08-29 23:13:52 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1504048432000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:13:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2017-08-29 23:13:53 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1504048433000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:13:53 America/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date": "2017-08-29 23:16:52 Etc/GMT",
        "expires_date_ms": "1504048612000",
        "expires_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:16:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000036088032",
        "is_trial_period": "true"
    },
    {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "onemonth_freetrial",
        "transaction_id": "1000000328796241",
        "original_transaction_id": "1000000328795138",
        "purchase_date": "2017-08-29 23:16:52 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1504048612000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:16:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2017-08-29 23:13:53 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1504048433000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:13:53 America/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date": "2017-08-29 23:21:52 Etc/GMT",
        "expires_date_ms": "1504048912000",
        "expires_date_pst": "2017-08-29 16:21:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000036088033",
        "is_trial_period": "false"
    }
]
```

The `latest_receipt_info` field will contain an array for every 'renewal' or 'transaction'. The way Apple handles free trials is by issuing one transaction that will always have `is_trial_period` be true, and subsequent non-trial renewal have `is_trial_period` be false. When you handle the receipt just make sure you are looking at the latest transaction by `purchase_date` or `expiration_date` which should represent the latest renewal and the one you should base unlocking content off of.

And regarding length in sandbox, if your IAP product has a free trial, the sandbox environment will issue one trial period, and 5 renewals, for six renewals total.

Comment: Does this two-receipt style work for sandbox and production in same manner?

Comment: Its actually separate transactions in one receipt, not separate receipts. And yes, sandbox and production behave the same way, the only difference is the time periods.

Comment: I'm trying to buy a subscription with a free trial, in sandbox environment, but when i try to purchase it, the popup doesn't tell anything about the free trial period, and in the receipt i see only a transaction. I've created a new sandbox user after i've set the free trial in the subscription